# Canonical URL specification via an HTTP header

Tags: http, header, seo, http-headers

I am using a canonical URL HTTP header for [search engine optimization (SEO)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Search_engine_optimization) purposes like this:

```
Link: /path/to; rel='canonical'
```

I can't find very much information on the subject, but the few examples I've seen are in this format:

```
Link: <http://example.com/path/to>; rel="canonical"
```

So my questions are:

- Are the angle brackets needed?
- Is the full URL with the scheme and host needed?
- Are double-quotes required for the `canonical` part?

Comment: http://support.google.com/webmasters/bin/answer.py?hl=en&answer=139394

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The answers are in http://greenbytes.de/tech/webdav/rfc5988.html#rfc.section.5: so "yes", "no", and "no".

(The link relation "canonical" has it's own spec -- https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc6596 -- but of course uses the general header field syntax defined in RFC 5988)

Answer (score 1):

Canonical links are implemented by placing the "link-to" URL inside angle brackets and putting the `link` HTML element in the page to which it applies:

```
<link rel="canonical" href="http://www.link-to-page-here.com/" />
```

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Canonical_link_element

Comment: That's a different method of doing it; I am looking for more information about the `HTTP` header method because the html header method is unavailable to me for these.  Details here http://support.google.com/webmasters/bin/answer.py?hl=en&answer=139394 (note that this page *also* talks about the html element).